# libGDX android sdk tools

Tags: java, android, sdk, libgdx

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oENu8.png)

Hi, I have this problem to generate a project of libGDX, how I can update android sdk tools?

Answer (score 4):

Click `Tools -- SDK manager` menu, scroll down you will find 28.0.3, check it and press OK.
[image]